# Sorting mock objects in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a class with mockito. It contains these methods:

- `add(Sortable s)`
- `List<Sortable> get()`

The class does several things to the objects internally, and it is *dependant on sorting the Sortable objects*.

The problem is that I am mocking Sortable, which makes *compareTo() always return 0*. Is there a way to make a Sorting mock that has the original Sortable compareTo() implementation? Or are there other ways to solve this?

Comment: create mockito `Spy` instead and mock only methods you need

Comment: I was considering `spy`, but the objects has so many other dependencies that it would be cumbersome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use statement like this before mocked object compareTo() method calling:

```
when(mockedObject.compareTo(any(Sortable.class))).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Comment: Wow. I dreamed about something like `thenCallRealMethod()`, but didn't expect it to actually exist...

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot call abstract real method on java object!
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking non abstract method.

Any suggestions?